# What is the difference showing JFrame using a invokeLater and without?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, invokelater

this is the documentacion:

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event
>   dispatching thread. This will happen after all pending AWT events have
>   been processed. This method should be used when an application thread
>   needs to update the GUI. In the following example the invokeLater call
>   queues the Runnable object doHelloWorld on the event dispatching
>   thread and then prints a message.

but i want to know how it means in code

I always made a program like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/**
 *
 * @author Robin
 */

public class Example {

    JFrame Frame=new JFrame();


    public Example() {

        Frame.setTitle("Example");
        Frame.setName("Example");
        Frame.setSize(300, 300);
        Frame.setResizable(false);
        Frame.setUndecorated(false);
        Frame.setLayout(null);
        Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setIconImage(CrearIcono(Color.decode("#F4141D")).getImage());
        Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Formato();
        Accion();
        Mover(Frame.getGlassPane());
        Frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private void Formato() {


    }

    private void Accion() {


    }

    public ImageIcon Imagen( String dir){return new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/lib/"+dir));}

    public static void Mover(final Component objeto) {
        MouseInputAdapter d=new MouseInputAdapter() {int x,X,y,Y;
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){x=e.getXOnScreen();X=objeto.getLocation().x;y=e.getYOnScreen();Y=objeto.getLocation().y;}
        @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){objeto.setLocation(X+(e.getXOnScreen()-x), Y+(e.getYOnScreen()-y));}};
        objeto.addMouseListener(d);objeto.addMouseMotionListener(d);
    }

    public int CentrarX(int AnchoObjeto, int AnchoRespectoA){return (AnchoRespectoA/2)-(AnchoObjeto/2);}
    public int CentrarY(int LargoObjeto, int LargoRespectoA){return (LargoRespectoA/2)-(LargoObjeto/2);}
    public int ImgA(JLabel imagen){return imagen.getIcon().getIconWidth();}
    public int ImgL(JLabel imagen){return imagen.getIcon().getIconHeight();}

    public static ImageIcon CrearIcono(Color color) {
        int WIDTH = 32;
        int HEIGHT = 32;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        int[] xPoints = {WIDTH, 0, 0, WIDTH / 2};
        int[] yPoints = {0, WIDTH / 2, WIDTH, WIDTH};
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
        g2.dispose();

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        return icon;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Example Ventana=new Example();
    }


}
```

what is better? what is the difference?

**SwingUtilities.invokeLater**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pantalla principal=new pantalla();   
            Calendario s=new Calendario(1); 
        }
    });       
}
```

**Without invokeLater**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            Example Ventana=new Example();
        }
```

thanks for your advices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one using `invokeLater(..)` is better in that it is the correct way to create a GUI.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) (and particularly 'Initial Threads') for more details.

Comment: @WearFox its correct because its safer. It ensures that your UI is initialised within the context of the EDT. In particular, you can look at [Inital Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) from the link Andrew has provided and search for "Swing single thread rule" on Google for more details